# When UAC is ON WPF application start is very slow for different user

Tags: wpf, uac

When UAC is turned ON then WPF application start/launch is very slow in Windows 7. Whenever I start any WPF application with same user who logged on to the machine then it works fine. 
But if application is started with different user- not the one who is currently logged into the machine but has admin access-then application start is very slow,same as run as different user.
Any idea what could be the reason for slow start when UAC is turned on and user is different than the currently logged on user.
Issue is similar to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8b6dc70-1421-4e05-bc21-1ebb638ab866/wpf-and-custom-credential-provider-in-windows-7?forum=wpf) & [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9b6e714f-afb8-4cc4-86da-40cd7531c565/wpf-loads-slowly-on-logon-and-switch-user-when-launched-from-custom-credential-provider?forum=wpf).
When I manually start the "Tablet PC Input Service" then this issue goes away and application launches fast.
I am using .NET 4.5 on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you confirmed that running ANY application as another user is slow or not? It might be something wrong with your Windows.

Comment: It is only for WPF application